# Why Lucene's analyzer's normalize method needs a field name

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I started to use the Lucene search library (v9.7.0). It works fine and as expected but I don't understand some API. Maybe there exists the best way to go?

I use StandardAnalizer for indexing and preparing search terms. The question is - why StandardAnalizer#normileze requires a field name? I found out that it is not necessary to pass it

```java
new FuzzyQuery(new Term("title", analyzer.normalize(null, "foo")), 1)
```

I have to pass null and it smells